# Same style to multiple children

Tags: css

I want to make few elements like `.condition`, `.operator`, `.value` hidden within `.disabled`, so I write css as

```
.disabled .condition, .disabled .operator, .disabled .value {display:none}
```

but my list of children is very large, hence there is so much repetative `.disabled` there. Is there any way to avoid it? may be like

```
.disabled [.condition, .operator, .value] {display:none}
```

Comment: Could you please add the HTML structure ?

Comment: You can add a class to all those elements that needs to be hidden and then write in styles `.disabled .yourclass { display: none; }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the `.disabled` is at the parent you can use a [Child Selector](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_element_gt.asp) `.disabled > .content1, .content2, .content3`

```css
div {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: red;
  margin: 1px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 50px;
}

.disabled>.content1,.content2,.content3 {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="disabled">
  <div class=" content1 ">1</div>
  <div class=" content2 ">2</div>
  <div class=" content3 ">3</div>
  <div class=" content4">4</div>
  <div class=" content5">5</div>
  <div class=" content6">6</div>
</div>
```

In addiction can look at the [CSS Selector Reference](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp) for a complete list of other selector.

Answer (score 0):

You can use your HTML tags for more "general selection", for example :

```
 .disabled > span {
    display: none;
 }
```

if you have more hidden elements than visible, you can try something like :

```
 .disabled > span:not(.some):not(.visible):not(.elements) {
    display: none;
 }
```

You can also just add a *'hidden'* class whithin your html to all the elements you want to hide.

```
 .hidden {
    display: none;
 }
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this :

```
.disabled .condition, .disabled .operator, .disabled .value {visibility: none;}
```

Answer (score -2):

With LESS or SASS, you can do something like :

```
    .disabled {
        .condition, .operator, .class2 {
            display: none;
        }
    }
```

http://www.hongkiat.com/blog/less-basic/

Comment: I am not aware of either of them, can I have solution in pure css?